# Is there an option to check if a opened page sucessfully loaded

Tags: javascript, window.open

I want to open an random page and also check if it loaded or not. The problem is, that even if the link doesn't exist the variable is still a reference to the new tab.

So is there any way to open a new link and check if the page loaded?

```
// get a random number
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 23900);

// open the page with the number
var x = window.open(document.getElementById(i).innerHTML);

// ?check if page is loaded?

// if not close page
x.close()
```

Comment: No. "It is because of the cross-domain script security restriction (also referred as the "Same Origin Policy")" -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: However, if you are in control of the pages that are being loaded, then you could post something to the server from the page being loaded and then run a check from the parent page to the server to see if that script has completed for the new window using a call to the server.

Comment: Are you in control of the sub-page?